# How to retrieve mat-checkbox value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am a beginner with angular material. I have written this code so far:

```js
Answer {
    id: string;
    content: string;
}
```

```html
<section *ngFor="let opt of step.answers">
                            <mat-checkbox [checked]="opt.id" (change)="check($event)">
                                <p [innerHTML]="opt.content"> </p>
                           </mat-checkbox> 
</section>
```

I still can't figure out how to retrieve the id for every option selected in every stepper and collect them in array

Comment: can u add step.answers model to your question please

Comment: @Çağrı I added the answers model as you asked.

Comment: I edit answer.. U can solve it by adding one variable and one attribute to your model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so this is the solution I've found, it's close to @Çağrı proposition but I changed few things since "event" has an attribute checked that I can use without needing to use a variable to save the value of "isChecked"

```js
check(event, opt, userResponse) {

        var rep = [];
      
        if (event.checked === true) {
            userResponse.push(opt);
        }

        if (event.checked === false) {
            var index: number = userResponse.indexOf(opt);
            userResponse.splice(index, 1);
            
        }
    }
```

```html
<section *ngFor="let opt of step.answers"  >
   <mat-checkbox (change)="check($event,opt,step.userResponse)">
       <p [innerHTML]="opt.content"> </p>
    </mat-checkbox> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

in [checked] condition u can't put id. It is true false condition. U should add one attribute more of step.answers model which calls ischecked whose initial value is false. and create global array called choosenanswers ,and write

```
Answer {
    id: string;
    content: string;
    ischecked:boolean=false;
}
```

then

```
 <section *ngFor="let opt of step.answers">
         <mat-checkbox [checked]="opt.ischecked" (change)="check($event)">
              <p [innerHTML]="opt.content"> </p>
          </mat-checkbox> 
    </section>
```

then in check event in components

```
  check(event){
      this.choosenanswers=[];
      this.step.answers.foreach(x=>{if(x.ischecked){ this.choosenanswers.push(x.id);}})
    }
```